# Visualforce pages may not display more than 10 dependent picklists together with their controlling fields.

Tags: visualforce, dependent-picklist

I am trying to create a VF Page with more than 10 dependent Picklist fields. I am getting the below error :

***Visualforce pages may not display more than 10 dependent picklists together with their controlling fields. This includes any picklists in components or inline pages***.

After going through few blogs, i see that salesforce limits only 10 dependent picklist fields on VF Page. Is there any work around to display more than 10 dependent picklist. Please need help here.

Comment: Did you get solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

**Limits for Custom Picklists**

> Custom single-select picklists can have:
>
> - Up to 1,000 values
> - Up to 255 characters per value
> - Note: These limits apply to custom restricted and unrestricted picklists.
>
> Custom multi-select picklists can have:
>
> - Up to 500 values
> - Up to 255 characters per value
>
> Users can select up to 100 values at a time on a record. You can have
>   up to 500 global picklists (or picklist value sets) in an org. Each
>   global value set can contain up to 500 values. These limits don’t
>   apply to custom picklists that use global picklist value sets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my question is regarding the number of fields and not the number of values or characters in the picklist field.

Comment: Wlcm, You can create up to 500 global picklists. There is no limit mentioned in salesforce for dependent pick-list.